# Categorizing and organizing list based on specific Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data dump of tickers (List 1), that I need to organize in a sheet based on categories (List 2) that I assign them.  Example below: List 2 will seldom change but some tickers/categories will be added removed.  And List 1 will change daily, but will always have a match on List 2.

List 1:

```
USD  
QQQ 
TSLA  
AAPL  
GOOGL  
SPY  
XLB  
XLK
```

List 2:

```
USD - Cash  
QQQ - Broad Market  
TSLA - Single Stock  
AAPL - Single Stock  
GOOGL- Single Stock  
SPY - Broad Market  
XLB - Sector  
XLK - Sector
```

I want it to look like the below:

List 3:

```
Broad Market  
QQQ  
SPY  

Sector:  
XLB  
XLK  

Single Stock:  
TSLA  
AAPL  
GOOGL  

Cash
```

I have been trying to figure this out and I am at a standstill.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think some info is missing: why is list 1 needed? The expected result can easily be achieved with the content of list 2 only.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad List 1 is the data dump we receive daily, and List 2 is the criteria that we need in order to make it look like List 3 if that makes sense.  List 1 is purely the raw data.